# MSSql Parent child relationship, retrieve top child and join other table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parent-child

So I have this table structure here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5836b (similar) and below. The PForecast table would have forecast on top level (parent) productsku. Once I obtain a list of forecast items in a given period, I need to retrieve product detail for the child with the highest priority (Ppriority) number (for that parent sku). Would also like to list all other child sku's concatenated in a separate column(optional).

```
create TABLE PForecast (ID INT, sku INT, qty int, entrydate datetime);

INSERT INTO PForecast  (ID, sku, qty, entrydate)
VALUES(10, 29490, 1, '2016-09-04 00:00:00.000'),
(19, 112407, 1, '2016-09-04 00:00:00.000'),
(11, 112407, 1, '2016-11-14 00:00:00.000'),
(12, 112344, 12, '2016-01-24 00:00:00.000'),
(13, 112344, 17, '2016-02-05 00:00:00.000'),
(14, 112344, 11, '2016-06-03 00:00:00.000'),
(15, 264856, 7, '2016-05-09 00:00:00.000'),
(16, 26480, 9, '2016-07-18 00:00:00.000'),
(17, 264856, 4, '2016-09-27 00:00:00.000'),
(18, 29490, 2, '2016-12-02 00:00:00.000');


create TABLE AllProd2 (sku INT, ID INT, descrip varchar(100), dept varchar(100),
                       SubDept varchar(100), class varchar(100), SubClass varchar(100),
                      Vcode INT, PID INT, Ppriority INT, parentFlag VARCHAR(1));

INSERT INTO AllProd2  (sku, ID, descrip, dept, SubDept, class, SubClass, Vcode, PID, Ppriority, parentFlag)
VALUES
(169243, 21177, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043419,  1, 'C'),
(136643, 21394, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043419,  2, 'C'),
(112344, 1043419, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043419,    NULL, 'P'),
(104516, 122, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428,    2, 'C'),
(111508, 130, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428,    1, 'C'),
(112407, 1043428, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428,    NULL, 'P'),
(115106, 17043838, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428,   3, 'C'),
(161835, 116050567, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428,  4, 'C'),
(238777, 1198119585, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043428, 5, 'C'),
(255210, 2092139762, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043555, 2, 'C'),
(264856, 1043555, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043555,    NULL, 'P'),
(264863, 1043556, '14 DIA PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043555,    1, 'C'),
(239124, 1995137332, '14 RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043890,    1, 'C'),
(266473, 1043889, '14 RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043890,   2, 'C'),
(266480, 1043890, '14 RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 1043890,   NULL, 'P'),
(26480, 10430, '14 PC/RD', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0007, 10430, NULL, 'P'),
(29490, 14480, '14 PC/RD hkj', 'abc', 'def', 'xyz', 'gty', 0004, 14480, NULL, 'N')
;
```

Would be better if I can build a temp table with the data set as I need to obtain more info and join other tables after this step.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please include an example or the desired results.  It's unclear exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The query will select all items within a date range from the forecast table, as you can see from my table design, the forecast only has parent sku and no child sku. So the next step would be to obtain the child sku(for that parent record) from the product table and build a new result set for the detailed forecast. i.e., SKU 26480 has 3 entries in the forecast table, my end result should be like this:

Comment: Updated comment: The query will select all items in a date range from forecast, as you can see in fiddle, forecast only has parent sku. The next step is to get the child sku(for that parent record) from the prod table and build new result set for the detailed forecast. i.e., SKU 112344 has 3 entries in the forecast table, If I look at the product table, the parent ID for that SKU is 1043419. This query should capture the highest ranked Ppriority and get that whole row. So my end result should be like this:         SKU:136643 ID: 21394  VCode: 4 ParentID: 1043419 ParentPriority: 2 ParentFlag: C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading your comment, I think you're looking for something like the following:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2016-06-01', @endDate DATE = '2016-12-01'
SELECT A.*, STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN PPriority IS NULL THEN 'P' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SKU) ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, SKU) END
    FROM AllProd2
    WHERE PID = A.PID
    AND ISNULL(PPriority, 0) <> A.PPriority
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN PPriority IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, PPriority
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '') OtherSKU
-- INTO #tmpResults
FROM (SELECT SKU 
    FROM PForecast 
    WHERE entrydate >= @startDate 
    AND entrydate <= @endDate 
    GROUP BY SKU) P 
LEFT JOIN AllProd2 A ON P.SKU = (SELECT SKU FROM AllProd2 WHERE ID = A.PID)
WHERE ISNULL(PPriority, 0) = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(PPriority, 0)) FROM AllProd2 WHERE PID = A.PID)
```

This gives the following for the specified date range:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+---------+------+---+-----------------------------------------+
|  26480 |      10430 | 14 PC/RD     | abc | def | xyz | gty | 7 |   10430 | NULL | P | NULL                                    |
|  29490 |      14480 | 14 PC/RD hkj | abc | def | xyz | gty | 4 |   14480 | NULL | N | NULL                                    |
| 136643 |      21394 | 14 DIA PC/RD | abc | def | xyz | gty | 4 | 1043419 | 2    | C | P112344, 169243                         |
| 238777 | 1198119585 | 14 DIA PC/RD | abc | def | xyz | gty | 4 | 1043428 | 5    | C | P112407, 111508, 104516, 115106, 161835 |
| 255210 | 2092139762 | 14 DIA PC/RD | abc | def | xyz | gty | 4 | 1043555 | 2    | C | P264856, 264863                         |
+--------+------------+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+---+---------+------+---+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi ZLK, this is very helpful. What I really want happen is all forecast needs to be listed. There are 5 distinct SKU's in the forecast table. They all need to come up and from the AllProd table, I would like product details pulled. if there are child sku's for the selected item in forecast, I would like to pull up only the child with the highest priority number. Hope I was able to clarify.

Comment: I've updated the query to give what I think you're asking for. If a "parent" has no "children", it just displays the parent. If a "parent" has "children", it displays the child with the highest PPriority. Or are you looking for all the parents to be displayed plus the child with the highest Ppriority (if one exists)?

Comment: Thanks so much. So this gets me what I need.